# Database Backup and Full-Text Search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running SQL Server 2005 EE.

When trying to perform a full database backup I receive the error message:

> Failed to pause catalog for backup. Backup was aborted.BACKUP DATABASE
>   is terminating abnormally.

After googling the issue, it seemed to be related to Full-Text Search not running properly, and so I checked and sure enough FTS was stopped. However, when attempting to start FTS, I recieved the following error message:

> Service Dependency Deleted (ObjectExplorer)

I googled this error and found the following advice in a [WordPress blog](http://maniish.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/service-dependency-deleted-in-sql-server-when-enabling-full-text-search/) (kind of worried about following this advice as there was no explanation about why I would do this).

> 1. Open the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet 
>      \Services\msftesql
> 2. Rename the value DependOnService to anything
> 3. Restart the server

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the registry changes? Seems pretty harmless to put it back if the change does nothing.

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you using? I've seen this before with SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008.


Issue relates to depending on a service that is not present in Windows Server >2003.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue, the ObjectExploer service doesn't exist in the same context on Windows server 2008, which is what i am assuming you are running (Server 2003 EOL's soon, so i am gussing you're no longer on it). I backed up the registry and did the same registry edit you found and everything went fine.

One can't be certain if your environment or systems are setup the same as mine were at the time, so make sure to backup everything you can before you go ahead with it. In my case we never purposely utilized the full-text search feature although it was enabled.